# Close Current form open new one of that form closed

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio

i have 2 form 
in form 1 i have a button when i click on button form 2 will be show and my data are showing on form 2 so far its OK
but i want when one of form 2 its open if user click on button in form 1 then close this form 2 and open a new one! not open an other form 2
i hope u understand my question :D sorry for bad English

i tried form instance function but its not working its just hold this form 2 and will not allow to open new one! 
with these code:

```
    public static Form2 Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_form2 == null)
            {
                _form2 = new Form2();
            }
            return _form2;

        }
    }
```

and here is button code :

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            if (RadioMale.Checked == true)
            {
                jensiyat = "مرد";
            }
            else { jensiyat = "زن"; }
            if (RadioMarried.Checked == true)
                tahol = "متاهل";
            else tahol = "مجرد";
        Class1.txt +=
           "________________________\n\n" + "مشخصات مربوط به  خانم/آقای " 
           + tbFamily.Text + "\n________________________" +
            "\nنام و نام خانوادگی: " + tbName.Text + " " +
            tbFamily.Text + "\n" + "ایمیل: " + tbEmail.Text + "\n" + "شماره ملی: " +
            tbCodmeli.Text + "\n" + "سریال شناسنامه: " +
            tbSerialShenasname.Text
            + "\nشهر محل زندگی: "+ shahr + " - " + TreeShahr.SelectedNode.Text
            + "\nآدرس: " + tbAddress.Text + "\n"
            + " تحصیلات : " + ComboTahsilat.SelectedItem
            + "\nجنسیت : " +jensiyat
            + "\nوضعیت تاهل: " + tahol
            + "\nتاریخ تولد: " + BirthTimePicker.Value.ToPeString()
            + "\n__________________________________________________";

        Form frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.Show();
    }
```

Comment: for clarification: you want the if the `Form2` is open and the user presses on `Form1` the button again --> then close the current `Form2` and open a new one? If so, please post the code of this button where you open the `Form2`. The solution is exactly there.

Comment: yeah i want exactly what u say!
i edit the question and add the button code

Comment: If you declare the `Form frm2 = new Form2();` outside of the method you will have control over the window and you can close it in this method if the button is clicked again. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the Variable for the `Form2` as class variable outside of the scope of the `btnSave_Click` method. This way you will be able to access it again when the button is clicked a second time.

```
Form frm2 = new Form2();

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if(frm.Visible)  // check whether the form is already showing
    {
        frm.Close();  // if yes close it first
    }

    frm2 = new Form2(); // then make a new form and show it
    frm2.Show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Application.OpenForms`. Gets a collection of open forms owned by the application.

```
 List<Form> forms = new List<Form>();

  // All opened myForm instances
  foreach(Form f in Application.OpenForms){
     if (f.Name == "Form2"){
        f.Close();
        break;
     }
  }
```

You can Show form like

```
Form2 ff = new Form2();
ff.Show();
```

Comment: where should i paste this code? in the button ? i do it 
but its not different !
and i got this erorr : name space _form2 not be found (you missed a reference ) ?

Comment: Where user click on button in form 1

Comment: yeah i do it :( but not worked
i added the button code in the question
the name space not found